# Disable Delete Data Relationship in Voyager

Tags: laravel, voyager

How to disable delete in voyager, when the id has been used in another table?

[image]

Comment: create a policy for the delete action, indicating that the model to be deleted cannot have relationships, and then apply it to the controller and the blade. +info: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization

Comment: Must i custom Policy and enforce it in a BREAD (Voyager)?